# MySQL create trigger declare

Tags: mysql, triggers, declare

I am trying to complete this question

**
Produce an audit trail (in a separate table) that records the current username, system date & grade change when someone attempts to update a Students grade
**

Here are the tables and columns

```
Module (code,credits,cost,name)
session (code,date,room)
Exam (no,code,grade)
course (code,credits,name)
Student (no,name,cell)
```

Here is the code I have so far

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `HarlemHS`$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`HarlemHS`@`%`
TRIGGER `HarlemHS`.`ExamChange`
AFTER UPDATE ON `HarlemHS`.`Exam`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO NEW.GradeUpdateLog Date_Of_Change,old_grade) 
        VALUES (CURDATE(), grade);
    END$$
```

I know I have to use DECLARE somewhere but not too sure where to use it and what to put in the DECLARE statement.

If i have missed anything let me know,

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: declare is only necessary if you're going to be using local variables. You're not - you're just taking some values from the record that caused the trigger to run, and using those values in an insert query.

Comment: I tried to run this and was getting 
ERROR 1142: INSERT command denied to user
I have been told to use declare statements instead?

Comment: that just means that the user that this trigger is running as doesn't have insert rights on your `gradeupdatelog` table.

Comment: Ahh ok ,any suggestions on what i should do? :)

Comment: grant your harlemhs account insert rights on the appropriate table...

Comment: i have tried doing that , i dont have the rights to grant access :(

Comment: then either get the rights granted to you by someone who can, find another table to write to that you DO have the rights on, or... you're stuck and can't proceed.

Comment: ok thanks fot your help :/